# C# Delegate as object

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, nunit, method-group

Disclaimer: the unit-test related info for this question is not really relevant - you can skip to ***"The Problem"*** if you're not familiar with this, but it helps set the context.

I have a class that I need to unit-test. It looks like this:

```
public class NumberParser {
    public static void CheckByteRange(string str){...}
    [...]
    public static void CheckFloatRange(string str){...}
    [...]
}
```

I want to use an NUnit [parametrized unit-test](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5) to test all these methods. Here's the test method:

```
    [TestCaseSource("CheckRange_Overflow_Inputs")]
    public void CheckRange_Overflow(string value, Action<string> method)
    {
        Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => method(value));
    }
```

The test uses `TestCaseSourceAttribute` to specify a field that contains a list of sets of arguments to the test method.

Now, NUnit expects a field called `CheckRange_Overflow_Inputs`, of type `object[]`, that itself contains `object[]` elements, each of which contains values for the arguments to the test method.

### The problem:

Ideally, I'd like to write the field like this:

```
    private static readonly object[] CheckRange_Overflow_Inputs
        = new object[]
              {
                  new object[]{byte.MaxValue,  NumberParser.CheckByteRange },
                  [...]
                  new object[]{float.MaxValue, NumberParser.CheckFloatRange },
                  [...]
              };
```

But the compiler complains it can't cast a method group to an object.

That makes sense - `NumberParser.CheckByteRange` could be ambiguous, e.g. it could be overloaded.

But how can I get the compiler to allow me to save (as an object) *the method called `NumberParser.CheckByteRange` that takes a `string` and returns `void`* ?

**What I tried** (and <del>failed</del> succeeded):

```
 [...]
 new object[]{byte.MaxValue, (Action<string>)NumberParser.CheckByteRange },
 [...]
```

Comment: Hmm, have you tried something like: `(string s) => NumberParser.CheckByteRange(s)`? It does not look that good, but maybe it will help a bit?

Comment: Well, I just want to point out that this question is a joy to read :) I wish everyone was writing questions like this

Comment: Please can you add the exact message (copy/paste, ideally) you are getting from the compiler about this.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Thanks, I do my best. If I'm going to get free help, the least I can do is try to make it easy for the benevolent souls to help me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method was `static`, then your attempt would have worked. It can't work simply as

```
(Action<string>)NumberParser.CheckByteRange
```

when `CheckByteRange` is an instance (non-`static`) method because you haven't told it which instance (`this`) to use. So either:

- make `CheckByteRange` into a `static` method
- tell it which instance to use, i.e. `(Action<string>)someInstance.CheckByteRange`

With them `static`, the following compiles fine for me:

```
private static readonly object[] CheckRange_Overflow_Inputs
    = new object[]
          {
              new object[]{byte.MaxValue,  (Action<string>) NumberParser.CheckByteRange },
              new object[]{float.MaxValue, (Action<string>) NumberParser.CheckFloatRange },
          };
```

Comment: @Cristi if I make them `static`, the code you have posted as "**What I tried** (and failed)" compiles. What error are you seeing, ***exactly***?

Comment: PEBKAC... The code above is contrived from the actual class I want to test. I was convinced the methods return `void`, but they don't. Changing to `(Func<string, float>) NumberParser.CheckFloatRange` does the trick.